# Image Dimensions in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

If I do the following :-

```
<asp:Image Id="img1" Height="100px" Width="100px" ImageUrl="/picture.jpg/>
```

the rendered html will be roughly

```
<img src="/picture.jpg" style="height:100;width:100"/>
```

I see a lot of SEO apps etc that recommends that images should be

```
<img src="/picture.jpg" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

Is there any way of forcing asp.net of using height and width attributes instead of using style attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this in the code-behind file unfortunately.  For example, by tying into the `Page_Init` as follows:

```
void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    img1.Attributes["width"] = "100";
    img1.Attributes["height"] = "100";
}
```

Alternatively...

You could use a `<img runat="server" />` tag as follows:

```
<img src="~/picture.jpg" height="100" width="100" runat="server" />
```

ASP.Net will treat it as an [HtmlImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage.aspx) on the server.

Comment: Thanks Dana, its a shame, there's no property to let the user to choose the style they want.